# Draw 2 lines on separate canvases with same points Android

Tags: java, android, canvas

How can I draw a line on one canvas, while duplicating the line in the exact same points on another canvas. My friends told me to use the same listener events for both, but I can't figure out how to do that. I will give you the code for my canvas and lines.

```
package com.mypackage.morphing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FingerLine extends View {
private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
private final Paint mPaint;
private float startX;
private float startY;
private float endX;
private float endY;
private Line tempL;
private int idx = 0;

private boolean firstCanContext = false;

public FingerLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for(Line l : lines) {
        canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.endX, l.endY, mPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lines.add(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            lines.get(idx).endX = event.getX();
            lines.get(idx).endY = event.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // when the user lifts up
            lines.get(idx).endX = event.getX();
            lines.get(idx).endY = event.getY();
            idx++;
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void clearList(){
    lines.clear();
    idx = 0;
    invalidate();
}

public void removeLineNumber(int indexR){
    lines.remove(indexR);
    idx--;
    invalidate();
}
}

package com.mypackage.morphing;

public class Line {
float startX, startY, endX, endY;
public Line(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY) {
    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.endX = endX;
    this.endY = endY;
}
public Line(float startX, float startY) { // for convenience
    this(startX, startY, startX, startY);
}
}
```

Comment: Many ways to do so. I would just draw the lines on both onDraw methods. I dont get what are u trying to do ? And u can use line2D instead of your own Line class

Comment: I have 2 canvases on my main view. I would like to be able to draw on one (either) and have the line I've just drawn appear on the other canvas (the one not currently being drawn on by the user at that time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer (however it may look scary)

I have 3 classes working on this (not including main, I'll get to that).
The classes are LineController.java, Line.java, and EditingView.java. LineController contains the arraylist's for the objects, lines are the line objects (I just made my own for ease) and EditingView is the types of views I am drawing on top of.

LineController class

```
public class LineController {
    public ArrayList<Line> firstCanvas;
    public ArrayList<Line> secondCanvas;
    private int idx;
    LineController(){
        firstCanvas = new ArrayList<>();
        secondCanvas = new ArrayList<>();
        idx = 0;
    }
    public void addLine(Line l){
        firstCanvas.add(l);
        secondCanvas.add(l);
        idx++;
    }

    public void addLine(float x, float y){
        firstCanvas.add(new Line(x, y));
        secondCanvas.add(new Line(x, y));
        idx++;
    }

    public void addX(int index, float x){
        if(index <= idx){
            firstCanvas.get(index).endX = x;
            secondCanvas.get(index).endX = x;
        }
    }

    public void addX(float x){
        firstCanvas.get(firstCanvas.size() - 1).endX = x;
        secondCanvas.get(secondCanvas.size() - 1).endX = x;
    }

    public void addY(int index, float y){
        if(index <= idx){
            firstCanvas.get(index).endY = y;
            secondCanvas.get(index).endY = y;
        }
    }

    public void addY(float y){
        firstCanvas.get(firstCanvas.size() - 1).endY = y;
        secondCanvas.get(secondCanvas.size() - 1).endY = y;
    }

    public void clearLists(){
        firstCanvas.clear();
        secondCanvas.clear();
        idx = 0;
    }

    public boolean removeLast(){
        if(firstCanvas.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        if(firstCanvas.size() == 1){
            idx = 0;
            firstCanvas.clear();
            secondCanvas.clear();
        }else{
            idx--;
            firstCanvas.remove(idx);
            secondCanvas.remove(idx);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

EditingView class

```
public class EditingView extends View {
    private LineController lc;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private boolean drawingMode = true;
    private int closestIndex = -1;
    private Paint editDot;
    private Paint editLine;

    private boolean endOfLine;
    private boolean noLine = true;
    private Point lastTouch;
    private final static int MAX_DISTANCE = 100;
    private Line editingLine = null;

    private int viewIndex;

    public EditingView(Context context){
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        editDot = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        editLine = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        editDot.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        editLine.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }

    public EditingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public void init(LineController controller){
        lc = controller;
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(viewIndex == 0){ // first View
            for (Line l : lc.firstCanvas) {
                canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.endX, l.endY, mPaint);
            }
            if(!drawingMode){
                // if in edit, draw a line around the index we found
                if(closestIndex != -1) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(lc.firstCanvas.get(closestIndex).startX,
                            lc.firstCanvas.get(closestIndex).startY, 20, editDot);
                    canvas.drawCircle(lc.firstCanvas.get(closestIndex).endX,
                            lc.firstCanvas.get(closestIndex).endY, 20, editDot);
                }
            }
        }else if(viewIndex == 1){
            for (Line l : lc.secondCanvas) {
                canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.endX, l.endY, mPaint);
            }
            if(!drawingMode){
                // if in edit, draw a line around the index we found
                if(closestIndex != -1) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(lc.secondCanvas.get(closestIndex).startX,
                            lc.secondCanvas.get(closestIndex).startY, 20, editDot);
                    canvas.drawCircle(lc.secondCanvas.get(closestIndex).endX,
                            lc.secondCanvas.get(closestIndex).endY, 20, editDot);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawLine(MotionEvent event){
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lc.addLine(event.getX(), event.getY());
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                lc.addX(event.getX());
                lc.addY(event.getY());
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                lc.addX(event.getX());
                lc.addY(event.getY());
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
    }
    public void editLine(MotionEvent event){
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // run function to find the closest point based on that object
                lastTouch = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                editingLine = findClosestLine(); // this should be for any point on the screen
                if(editingLine == null){
                    noLine = true;
                }else{
                    noLine = false;
                    endOfLine = checkPointStartEnd(editingLine);
                }
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // edit the point to have the new points from the touch event
                if(!noLine){
                    // we found one
                    if(!endOfLine){
                        editingLine.startX = event.getX();
                        editingLine.startY = event.getY();
                    }else{
                        editingLine.endX = event.getX();
                        editingLine.endY = event.getY();
                    }
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(!noLine){
                    // we found one
                    if(!endOfLine){
                        editingLine.startX = event.getX();
                        editingLine.startY = event.getY();
                    }else{
                        editingLine.endX = event.getX();
                        editingLine.endY = event.getY();
                    }
                    editingLine = null;
                    invalidate();
                }
                lastTouch = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void editMode(int index){
        drawingMode = false;
        closestIndex = index;
    }

    public void clear() { closestIndex = -1; }

    public void drawingMode(){
        drawingMode = true;
    }

    public void viewIndex(int index){
        viewIndex = index;
    }

    // finds the closest line in either array (checks the screen right?)
    private Line findClosestLine(){
        int temp1, temp2;
        Line tempLine = null;
        int closestDistance = MAX_DISTANCE;
        // needs to loop through the array list, for both startX,Y and endX,Y of each line in the array
        // then needs to get the index to that point and draw a circle around that point
        // also change the colour of the line and the corresponding line based on that index

        if(viewIndex == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < lc.firstCanvas.size(); i++){
                temp1 = checkPoint(lc.firstCanvas.get(i));
                if(temp1 < closestDistance && temp1 != -1) {
                    tempLine = lc.firstCanvas.get(i);
                    closestIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < lc.firstCanvas.size(); i++){
                temp2 = checkPoint(lc.secondCanvas.get(i));
                if(temp2 < closestDistance && temp2 != -1){
                    tempLine = lc.secondCanvas.get(i);
                    closestIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return tempLine;
    }
    // Checks the point of a line to see if it is close
    private int checkPoint(Line l){
        int firstDistance = pyth((lastTouch.x - l.startX), (lastTouch.y - l.startY));
        int secondDistance = pyth((lastTouch.x - l.endX), (lastTouch.y - l.endY));
        if(MAX_DISTANCE > firstDistance) {
            return (int)firstDistance;
        }else if(MAX_DISTANCE > secondDistance){
            return (int)secondDistance;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    // Checks the line we have found for the close point being start or end
    private boolean checkPointStartEnd(Line l){
        boolean start = false;
        int firstDistance = pyth((lastTouch.x - l.startX), (lastTouch.y - l.startY));
        int secondDistance = pyth((lastTouch.x - l.endX), (lastTouch.y - l.endY));
        if(MAX_DISTANCE < firstDistance) {
            start = true;
        }else if(MAX_DISTANCE < secondDistance){
            start = false;
        }
        return start;
    }
    // returns pythagorian theorum
    private int pyth(double x, double y){
        int z;
        z = (int)Math.sqrt(((x * x) + (y * y)));
        return z;
    }
}
```

Line Class

```
public class Line {
    float startX, startY, endX, endY;
    public Line(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
    }
    public Line(float startX, float startY) { // for convenience
        this(startX, startY, startX, startY);
    }
}
```

MainActivity (only what's important)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            lc = new LineController();
            firstCanvas = new EditingView(this);
            secondCanvas = new EditingView(this);
            firstCanvas.viewIndex(0);
            secondCanvas.viewIndex(1);
            firstCanvas.init(lc);
            secondCanvas.init(lc);
            firstCanvas.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
            secondCanvas.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
            firstFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.firstFrame);
            secondFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.secondFrame);
            firstFrame.addView(firstCanvas);
            secondFrame.addView(secondCanvas);
    }

private class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            EditingView temp = (EditingView)v;
            if(drawingMode) {
                // drawing mode
                temp.drawLine(event);
                updateCanvas();
            }else{
                // edit mode
                temp.editLine(event);
                updateCanvas();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is all that I used. What happens is that I have a controller object created inside of the main and passed to the EditViews to hold the arrays. I then access only the arrays depending on the view that is being used. I then setup a touch listener created inside of the MainActivity (could be broken up) class that will be used to handle what mode the user is in, (either draw or edit). Using all this will allow me to create new views (programmatically) using the listener for the whole screen inside of the MainActivity.

I know this isn't the best way to do it all, but it works around and I could not find anything else. Hope this helps others who are looking to do something of the same thing. Or at least work towards their own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you would draw on one canvas and you would like to see the lines drawn appear on the second canvas, simply make a method in your class to "add a line". Whenever you add a line with that method (and subsequently draw it), notify a listener (in this instance, the second canvas) that a line has been added. That second canvas can then decide to draw that line as well (or to fetch the lines from the first canvas and redraw all of them).

Comment: Would this method be in my main class? Or in my view? @CountZukula

Answer (score 0):

So u have 2 classes, both extends View.
FirstView gets the Events when the user touches the screen.
u want SecondView to draw the same things as FirstView.

Your friend says u to add a Listener for both classes.
But u could also send Lines from FirstView to SecondView.
So u create an instance of SecondView in your firstView :

```
public class FirstView extends View {
    SecondView secondView;
```

Two choices now,

1) Both classes have the ArrayList, when a line is created or modified, u do it in both classes. Dont forget to refresh SecondView !

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Line line = new Line(event.getX(), event.getY());
            lines.add(line);
            secondView.lines.add(line);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            lines.get(idx).endX = event.getX();
            lines.get(idx).endY = event.getY();
            secondView.lines.get(idx).endX = event.getX();
            secondView.lines.get(idx).endY = event.getY();
```

2) Only FirstView has the ArrayList, And u draw all lines in both classe in the onDraw method. This is a bad idea because onDraw is called often, so u have to make the least work inside.

Comment: One problem I'm finding is that when I call add on my secondView it gives me an 'attempt to read null' error

Comment: to read null ? Did u instanciate your secondView, and her ArrayList ?

Comment: So u have to retrieve it. Please read the doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html